# Java SE + NetBeans - How to assign textfields to an array in UI Generator?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, jtextfield

I've generated a UI in NetBeans that has 16 text fields positioned 4x4. To be able to iterate through them dynamically, I wanted to have those text fields in an array so their names would be something like field[0] - field[15], but i have not found a way to do so. The editor allows me only to assign a specific variable for each field, and it doesn't accept "[]" and returns an error message "The name of a component must be a valid Java Variable name.".
I would prefer not to break the UI generator display by externally modifying the code, but if it's the only way to do this, then to hell with it. :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post some code too so that it will give a clearer idea of your problem.

Comment: The code is generated by netbeans and the problem was with generator not accepting arrays. I solved the problem by using the method in the first answer:
`fields = new JTextField[]{symbol1, symbol2, symbol3, symbol4, symbol5, symbol6, symbol7, symbol8, symbol9, symbol10, symbol11, symbol12, symbol13, symbol14, symbol15, symbol16};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no support for that sort of variable organization.

I have always approached it by adding something like this after the `initComponents()` call:

```
fields = new JTextField[]{ textField1, textField2, ... };
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I had the same idea, but I thought I was missing on something.